# SQL: Going through column with values from other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I have a table:

```
Client_ID   Day
------------------
1804    2018-10-22
1804    2018-10-23
1804    2018-10-24
1804    2018-10-25
1804    2018-10-26
1804    2018-10-29
1804    2018-10-30
1804    2018-10-31
1804    2018-11-02
1317    2018-10-24
1317    2018-11-23
```

Now what I want to do, is to take distinct values of each column and (probably with a while statement) check all date column values and have one more column with true or false statement if that id was on that date. So result should look like this:

```
Day       Client_ID Occur
-------------------------
2018.10.22  1804    TRUE
2018.10.23  1804    TRUE
2018.10.24  1804    TRUE
2018.10.25  1804    TRUE
2018.10.26  1804    TRUE
2018.10.29  1804    TRUE
2018.10.30  1804    TRUE
2018.10.31  1804    TRUE
2018.11.02  1804    TRUE
2018.11.23  1804    FALSE
2018.10.22  1317    Does not exist
2018.10.23  1317    Does not exist
2018.10.24  1317    TRUE
2018.10.25  1317    FALSE
2018.10.26  1317    FALSE
2018.10.29  1317    FALSE
2018.10.30  1317    FALSE
2018.10.31  1317    FALSE
2018.11.02  1317    FALSE
2018.11.23  1317    TRUE
```

For 1 ID I'm able to get the result with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [Day],
    CASE 
       WHEN Client_ID = '1804' 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
    END AS Occur
FROM 
    table
```

But I need this to go through all distinct values of column `Day`. And if some ID's lowest date is higher than lowest date in Day column, than it has to have a different result. Let's say "Does not exist" (but it can be anything). This is where I need some help.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: As you'll see from the discussion in the answers (below), you don't want to use a WHILE structure if you can avoid it.  RDBMS systems like SQL Server are a LOT happier if you give them set-based tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the rows with a `cross join` and use `left join` to bring in the values.  You need one additional constraint on the earliest date.  I think I would do:

```
select d.date, c.client_id,
       (case when d.date < c.min_date then 'Does not exist'
             when t.id is not null then 'TRUE'
             else 'FALSE'
        end) as occur
from (select distinct day from t) d cross join
     (select client_id, min(date) as min_date
      from <table> t
      group by client_id
     ) c left join
     <table> t
     on t.day = d.day and t.client_id = c.client_id;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff, this is exactly what I needed. Just there is one small mistake, on the second from the bottom line before "t" or after left join there has to be "table". Just for others to know that :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a `CROSS JOIN` that generates all possible combinations of date and id, combined with a `LEFT JOIN` on the original table, like :

```
SELECT
    d.date,
    i.id,
    CASE WHEN t.id IS NULL THEN 'FALSE'  ELSE 'TRUE' END
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT day FROM table) d
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table) i 
    LEFT JOIN table t
        ON t.date = d.date 
        AND t.id = i.id
```

Comment: @Larnu : yes right, thanks for pointing this out ! I was editing at the same time as you, just updated my answer to fix this typo

Comment: This looks really nice. I will try it out. Just I forgot one thing while writing original request and did not noticed that there answers so quickly while editing my post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make while loops on SQL Server, you could try this:

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <= #Number of loops here)
BEGIN
    #Your statements here
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
```

Comment: Not a wrong answer, but would definitely be one of the worst performing. Just a note to readers.

Comment: Agreed. Although the OP did assume they would likely need a `WHILE` loop, in actuality using one would be a poor choice. SQL Server, and other RDBMS, excel at set based operations, not iterative tasks; and a `WHILE` loop is most definately the latter. In the SQL World operations such as this are known as RBAR (Row By Agonising Row) operations and are generally best avoided.